# Casting from void* to int

Tags: c++, casting

Hello I'm trying to cast arguments from void* to int using

```
id=*((int *)x);
```

But I'm getting different values than the original value of x. I've read about using intptr_t but could not understand how to use it

Comment: Can you provide more context? Without seeing more about seeing more of the code I don't think we can help you.

Comment: Yeah, context would be nice. Someone who struggles with basic C++ syntax should probably not cast pointers to integers, that's extremely rarely needed and potentially quite dangerous. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You are not converting the value of `void*` into `int`, you are telling `void*` its a `int*`, and then fetching the `int` value from the memory address it is pointing to (aka dereferencing).

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee the value of `void*` fits in an `int`, thats where `intptr_t` comes in. `intptr_t` is essentially an `int` but the size of a pointer, whatever a pointer size is in your current architecture (32 or 64 bit).

Answer (score 2):

That's not a cast, that's a dereference. You want:

```
id = (int) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is casting void pointer to int pointer, not to int. You can cast void pointer to int directly, like this

```
int n = (int)p;
```

However, that is not guaranteed to work for all values of integer.

Instead, you should use intptr_t. Change parameter type from void pointer to intptr_t, and use the cast above. This is guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) it says that the `intptr_t` is optional, does this mean that some implementations of `<cstdint>` dont implement it? Does this mean not portable?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, and yes.

Comment: @Ben to add a bit more of context on the reasoning: some platforms may lack a specific way to convert a "pointer" to a single integer, especially if there are multiple kinds of pointers. Think of the segmented 8086 architecture, where a "pointer" could be "near" (16-bit offset) or "far" (16-bit segment + 16-bit offset). There is no _single_ way to represent _every_ pointer as an integer, or to do so without worsening the performance of "near" pointers.

Comment: How to use intptr_t?

Comment: @user3043108 In the same way as `int`, except that you need to include a header called `<cstdint>` Instead of writing `int n = (int)ptr` you would write `intptr_t n = (intptr_t)ptr`. Now `n` behaves like an integral type, but it holds a pointer.